# Unity 3D Launcher Color/Transparency with MyUnity 3.0

Tags: unity, launcher, 3d

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS beta. I installed MyUnity 3.0 to be able to control the color and opacity of the launcher to override the whole chameleon idea. So far it seems the transparency setting works (under 'launcher' tab), but the color doesn't. The color of the launcher will update when I change it, but when I close MyUnity it reverts back to chameleon immediately. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a bug report on this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/975350